# Shaitan or Jinn attached with a person all the time

Tags: hadith, shaitan

> Abdullah b. Mas'ud reported that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said:
>   There is none amongst you with whom is not an attache from amongst the jinn (devil). They (the Companions) said: Allah's Messenger, with you too? Thereupon he said: Yes, but Allah helps me against him and so I am safe from his hand and he does not command me but for good.

This from [Sahih Muslim](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/52/62) Chapter: The Mischief Of The Shaitan And How He Sends His Troops To Tempt People, And With Every Person There Is A Qarin (Companion From Among The Jinn)

**So Is there always a same jinn or shaitan (Qarin) with a person all the time and can someone able to refrain from his company.**

Comment: Nice query. Do you mean the negative sort of Jinn? (which would be such as Shaitan, or generally did you said that?) / JazakAllah-khaira for discussing such an interesting and beneficial query.

Comment: I meant The one which Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him mentioned in Hadith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, he is always there with you as what is mentioned in the Quraan in surah Qaf:

> (قَالَ قَرِينُهُ رَبَّنَا مَا أَطْغَيْتُهُ وَلَٰكِنْ كَانَ فِي ضَلَالٍ بَعِيدٍ)

His [devil] companion will say, "Our Lord, I did not make him transgress, but he [himself] was in extreme error.

[Surat Qaf 27]

The arabic word Kareen (قرين) means literally a consort or companion as in the translation, which is someone who remains with you forever, so based on its meaning, you cannot get rid of him. However, you can manage to resist his evil whispers, as Allah said:

> (إِنَّهُ لَيْسَ لَهُ سُلْطَانٌ عَلَى الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَعَلَىٰ رَبِّهِمْ يَتَوَكَّلُونَ)

Indeed, there is for him no authority over those who have believed and rely upon their Lord.

[Surat An-Nahl 99]

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

What refer to our jin is a symbolic term. It means every one of us has tendency to do bad things and in other hand good things. These tendencies make your character. If you try to do good things then your angel side is more powerful, and if you do bad things your devil part is more powerful. These are symbolic terms, you've to notice to the meaning, not talking about where is my devil. It's for about 15 centuries ago, when satisfing people is only by calling demon and angel.

God always say us "Think, Think and think in logic way.. ". Leave these words and establish your life on minded ways.

Comment: So leaving the words of Hadith would be minded ways? and Islam is not ONLY  based on logics but it also asks us to have eman too which has some belief ,,how we are able to prove the existence of angels ,judgement day just with logics.

Comment: @servant : If you wanna be a good man and do what the God tell us to do, you don't need to believe in demons or angels. Doing what the God say us to do is all distinct from these illogical words. Indeed believing in the Judgment day is the main principle of believing in actions and reactions. What you do is not wasted. You've to answer about your actions. You see it's all pure logical.

Comment: The Islam is based on Humanity and Logical actions. If you're a pure man you will believe in Islam immediately, because of it's logical ways in actions. It's more important than believing in angels and demons. These are only side part of religion that you can't deny it or prove it. It looks like useless information that don't deserve precise attention in choosing the path of your life.

Comment: Can we consider that non believers who dont have "Belief" just by following logics would be granted Jannah by Allah swt and what questions are gonna asked in graves according to hadith ,, would that be logics or beliefs?

Comment: @ Hope Islam is very balanced it gives fundamental beliefs as well as logical explanations so here the question was not about which is more important ,If you read just Quran you would not completely be able to understand so Mufassir have made it easy to understand that which ayah was revealed in what circumstances so tafseer as subject of Islamic sciences is being taught now ,similarly muhaddith have done a lot of work on Hadith and the question was about the interpretation of hadith not about fundamentals v/s belief –